# system() command with a variable in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

Here I come with another noob question: I'm trying to write a very simple program in Swift and got stuck when trying to run a shell command from within the program using a variable.

A quick example: writing `system("say hello")` works.

But the following code doesn't work:

```
var whatToSay = "hello world"
system("say \(whatToSay)")
```

The error I get when building the program is: `Could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolatingSegment'`

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast to obtain `CString`:

```
var whatToSay = "hello world"
var nsCommand : NSString = "say \(whatToSay)"
var command : CString? = nsCommand.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
system(command!)
```

**EDIT:**

If you use it often, you can use an extension for `String`:

```
extension String {
    func toCString() -> CString? {
        let nsSelf : NSString = self
        return nsSelf.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}

var whatToSay = "hello world"
system("say \(whatToSay)".toCString()!)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was way beyond my knowledge.

Comment: In Swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.2) you only need to:

   `import Foundation

    var whatToSay = "hello world"
    system("say \(whatToSay)")`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.1 (Xcode 7.1), if you need to run a command like `say` in OS X you can also use NSTask, as shown in [this blog post](http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/25/how-to-execute-shell-commands-from-swift/)

Basically, something along the lines of (if you don't need to check command output, that is):

```
import Foundation

let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/say"
task.arguments = ["Hello", "World!"]

let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()
```